# Execute SSIS package from Visual Studio database project deployment?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

We have a nightly process that creates scrubbed copies of our databases so that our developers  can use them in their dev environment.  They restore the databases and then run the database deployment from a database project in Visual Studio 2010 to get updated schemas.

I'm working on an SSIS package that will copy data out of the primary database into staging tables and then into an archive for reporting.  Once completed I'd like the database deployment to kick off the SSIS package so that it updates the archive database, is there any way to do this?

The source and target databases will both be in the solution. I'm thinking the source database deployments will stay the same, with no dependencies on the target or vice versa. Deployments on the target db project are where the package execution would get called right after post-deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, add a step into your nightly process to start the SSIS package.  SQL Agent has a job step explicitly for starting SSIS packages but if your process isn't that, just make an operating system call to [DTEXEC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
dtexec.exe /file C:\RepliScrubberPackage.dtsx
```

Comment: I want the package to run on the dev computers whenever they do a database deployment from VS.  Can the deployment include a call to dtexec?

Comment: So your vision is they right click from within SSDT (VS 2010) and select Publish, after it does the deploy magic it should execute the SSIS package against the same target database?

Comment: Right click on db project->Deploy.  The source and target databases will both be in the solution.  I'm thinking the source database deployments will stay the same, with no dependencies on the target or vice versa.  Deployments on the target db project are where DTEXEC would get called right after post-deployment.  Thanks.